# Problem with charge transfer equation

Tags: charge, pmos

I'm confused on the two equations(refer to the figure: enclosed in red square)[image]
This is a 4-stage pmos charge pump, I understand why its delta Qg is multiplied by 4(underlined red) same goes with the delta Qgb and Qgt (refer to the circuit) however, [image]
In the second circuit above wherein it's a 2-stage PMOS charge pump, it confuses me on where did it get the multiplier 4 for the highlighted delta's Qg, Qgb and Qgt.

Can somebody help me figure out this one.

4-stage clock pattern:
[image]

2-stage clock pattern:
[image]

Comment: I'd tend to agree with you. It doesn't look like it makes any sense. It looks like a typo to me. It's probably a careless error when the author copied the equation from the previous 4 stage case. I'd double check it with your teacher. It's actually pretty common to find typos in technical texts. Hopefully by the 5th edition they fix all the errors, but even that's wishful thinking usually.

Comment: But based on eqn (9) it follows that it is true for N-stages. Or did I just missed some analysis based on the clock cycles used. (refer to figure above for clock cycles) @horta

Comment: It is true for N stages. That means that 4 stages should have double the charge that 2 stages does, which means just as you suspected eqn (6) appears to be wrong as the coefficients should be 2 rather than 4. In that way, there would be congruence between eqn 6, 16 & 9.